# Expected value vs probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value, birthday

Sorry in advance, it is probably a stupid question.
I encountered it when I was thinking about the birthday problem. The probability of having at least one pair of the same birthday is
$$ 1- \frac{365\cdot364\cdot\ldots\cdot(365-n+1)}{365^n}$$ and it is above 0.5 for n>22.
However the expected value for the number of pairs is
$$ E[\# \text{pairs of same birthdays}] = \binom{n}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{365}$$
which is larger than 1 for n>27.

So why is there a difference?

Comment: And then there is the expected number of birthdays which are shared which is $365-(364+n)\left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^{n-1}$ and is larger than $1$ for $n \ge 29$.  These are all different questions, so get different answers

Answer (score 1):

The classical birthday paradox computation concerns itself with the *median* of the number of pairs of same birthdays, which is not the *mean* or expected value. The two are usually not the same.

Answer (score 1):

There may be more than one match, which increases the expected value.